# Spring Boot with HTML

Tags: java, spring

I hava Spring Boot Application.I want to show html.

index.html location is following
templete/view/index.html

Controller.java

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "/view/index.html";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

return "view/index";
Should be what you need. In the future you might consider saying what you expect to happen and what actually happens, even better providing an error message which might give a hint like your file could not be found.

Comment: Thank you.I solved.I forgot this application apply thymeleaf.It should not add ".html".